# Creating an array with data conditional on another matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, conditional-statements, apply

I know there must be an apply function or ave for this, but I am not quite sure how to do it:

I have data:

```
     date player market 
 1:  1-1      1      1    
 2:  1-1      2      1    
 3:  1-1      1      2    
 4:  1-2      2      1    
 5:  1-2      3      2    
 6:  1-3     21      1    
 7:  1-4      1      1    
 8:  1-4     51      1    
 9:  1-4      1      1    
10:  1-5      1      2
```

I also have a blank array, which has unique dates on the rows, unique markets on the columns, and unique players for the third dimension.

```
1
[,,1]
    1  2
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
1-5


2
[,,2]
      1  2
1-1
1-2
1-3
1-4
1-5


etc
```

I want to fill out the array with from the data. 
I want each point to = 1 if the guy has an entry in the data where he is present for a date and market combination, and 0 if not.  So for example, for 1 and 2, they would be filled out as:

```
1
[,,1]
    1  2
1-1 1 1
1-2 0 0
1-3 0 0
1-4 0 1
1-5 0 1


2
[,,2]
      1  2
1-1  1   0
1-2  1   0
1-3  0   0
1-4  0   0
1-5  0   0
```

Looping is out of the question.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` for this purpose. Where temp dates, Month market and day player.

```
data(airquality)
tab<-xtabs(~Temp+Month+Day,airquality)

> dim(tab)
[1] 40  5 31


> str(tab)
 xtabs [1:40, 1:5, 1:31] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ Temp : chr [1:40] "56" "57" "58" "59" ...
  ..$ Month: chr [1:5] "5" "6" "7" "8" ...
  ..$ Day  : chr [1:31] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
 - attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~Temp + Month + Day, data = airquality)
```

edit:
converting to data frame.

```
> head(as.data.frame(tab))
  Temp Month Day Freq
1   56     5   1    0
2   57     5   1    0
3   58     5   1    0
4   59     5   1    0
5   61     5   1    0
6   62     5   1    0
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Cross-tabulation is amazing! Thank you!

Comment: If needed you can easily transform it into flat data.frame with just as.data.frame(tab). :)

Comment: What exactly does flat data frame mean? I get the error: long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1571

Comment: In this case you shoud have three id columns and dummy variable (0-1) denoting which interaction of id variables exists. Code `as.data.frame(tab)` gives me the "flat" data frame.

Comment: Oh yes! This is useful, but is it possible my data is too big to do that?  When I do head(as.data.frame(tab)), I get the error "Error in factor(x, levels = unique(x)) :
  long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1571
", even though the tab is the proper output as you described.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49842/discussion-between-maciej-and-robbieboy74)

Comment: You coud use `data.table` package `library(data.table); tab1<-as.data.table(tab); tab1`